# C++ : Creating an array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following class:

```
class student
{
    int rol , marks;
    char name[20];
    public:
    student(int r , int m , char n[])
    {
         rol = r;
         marks = m;
         strcpy(name,n);
    }
    int roll()
    {
        return rol;
    }
};
```

and now I am trying to create an array of objects like so:

```
student a[]= {(1,10,"AAA"),(2,20,"BBB"),(3,30,"CCC")}; // I get the error on this line
```

but I get this error message:

> Error:  testing.cpp(40,56):Cannot convert 'char *' to 'student[]'

When I do this :

```
student a(1,10,"AAAA");
student b(2,20,"BBBB");
student c(3,30,"CCCC");
student d[3]={a,b,c};
```

it works perfectly.

@WhozCraig Thx a lot . this is the solution to my problem:

I had to initialize the array as below:

```
student a[]= {
    student(1, 10, "AAA"),
    student(2, 20, "BBB"),
    student(3, 30, "CCC")
};
```

My initial code is wrong probably because the constructor cant create more than 1 object at a time.

Comment: 1. `student::student` third parameter should be `const char n[]`, and 2. replace every `(` with `{` and every `)` with `}` in your `a[]` declaration.

Comment: @WhozCraig when I do that I get about 10 error messages

Comment: [**See it live**](http://ideone.com/LWMd5w), and include whatever *exact* toolchain you're using *in your question*. Alternatively, you could [also just do this](http://ideone.com/pGfsww).

Answer (score 0):

In an expression `(1,10,"AAA")` means to apply the comma operator.  To initialize an array, you have to provide expressions that can initialize each array member. So one way is:

```
student a[] = {
    student(1, 10, "AAA"),    // creates a temporary student to use as initializer
    student(2, 20, "BBB"),
    student(3, 30, "CCC") };
```

Since C++11 you can write:

```
student a[] = {  {1, 10, "AAA"}, {2, 20, "BBB"}, {3, 30, "CCC"} };
```

because C++11 added the feature that an object's constructor can be called via a brace-enclosed initializer list. This is the same reason you could also write afterwards:

```
a[0] = { 4, 40, "DDD" };
```

Note: as mentioned in comments, `char n[]` should be `char const n[]`, and you could improve safety by using `std::string name;` instead of `char name[20];`.